# Why do my animations are not showing on first window load?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a window with a basic animation set to run when the window is loaded.

Here is the animation in the window:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Duration="00:00:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

And for reference, here is how this window is opened:

```
        PreferencesWindow PrefWindow = new PreferencesWindow();
        PreferencesWindowViewModel PrefWindowViewModel = new PreferencesWindowViewModel();
        PrefWindow.DataContext = PrefWindowViewModel;
        PrefWindow.Owner = p as MainWindow;
        PrefWindow.ShowDialog();
```

This is within a function called from an ICommand.

When you open the window the first time, it seems to do nothing for a second, then suddenly the window appears. All subsequent times you open the window however, the animation plays. Why wont the animation play on first open? What should I change?

PS, its not being caused by the new window being behind the old one, Ive tried other animations where it slides in from right of screen and tried hacing the new window smaller in size than the new one.

EDIT:
ICommand in response to comment:

```
    private ICommand openPreferences;
    public ICommand OpenPreferences
    {
        get
        {
            if (openPreferences == null)
            {
                openPreferences = new RelayCommand(OpenPreferencesEx, null);
            }
            return openPreferences;
        }
    }
    private void OpenPreferencesEx(object p)
    {
        PreferencesWindow PrefWindow = new PreferencesWindow();
        PreferencesWindowViewModel PrefWindowViewModel = new PreferencesWindowViewModel();
        PrefWindow.DataContext = PrefWindowViewModel;
        PrefWindow.Owner = p as MainWindow;
        PrefWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the `ICommand`?

Comment: some problems at code level, else everything works fine for me.

Comment: Added the code to answer first comment.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, and what is the implementation of RelayCommnd? On .NET 4.6.1, using a simple implementation of ICommand that simply invokes the supplied Action (otherwise the code is exactly the same as yours), I can't reproduce the problem. This makes me wonder whether .NET version, OS version, or the implementation  of RelayCommand, is a factor.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using just the information you've provided here. Please edit your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. I suspect that all that's really happening is that on your computer, there's some latency due to JITting, XAML loading, whatever and the animation happens but just not while the UI thread is able to present it. Have you tried extending the duration, e.g. to 10 seconds or longer, to see if eventually the UI thread catches up and starts showing you the animation, already begun?